# Change value of element inside img tag in JS

Tags: javascript

I have a HTML fragment like this to display a product image:

```
<img src="/some/path" border="0" id="bigImg"  data-zoom-image="/some/path">
```

The code data-zoom-image is a path to a larger image so on mouse over, it can zoom in on the image.

I also have a JavaScript function that when I click somewhere else it change that picture... like this:

```
function showLarge(path)
{
 var full_path = 'upload/product_image/large_'+path;
  document.getElementById("bigImg").src = full_path;
  document.getElementById("bigImg").data-zoom-image = full_path;
}
```

I want to also change the data-zoom-image value when the SRC of the image changes... I tried by adding the line `document.getElementById("bigImg").data-zoom-image = full_path;`  But it doesn't work... how should I do this...

Thank you

Comment: what does this have todo with php? you modifing data on the client (javascript) it does not matter with what you generated the data... 

your problem would be easy with jQuery: `$('#bigImg').data('zoom-image', full_path);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setAttribute` to changes the value of an existing attribute on the specified element.

```
document.getElementById("bigImg").setAttribute('data-zoom-image',full_path);
```

The document is here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute

Comment: its not working.... I even created a `var full_path2` and it's just not doing anything... my JS code is now: `var full_path = 'upload/product_image/large_'+path;
   var full_path2 = 'upload/product_image/large_1391300206_uunp4.jpg'; 
  document.getElementById("bigImg").src = full_path;
  document.getElementById("bigImg").setAttribute("data-zoom-image",full_path2);`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I guess you are using some kind of image zomming plug-in or library. In order to fix your problem, I would like to see more codes you are writing. Can you paste your code on JsFiddle?

Comment: @user3011784 I reviewed your code on JSFiddle. The links of following script is missing :<script src='http://www.bewolfclothing.com/elevatezoom/jquery-1.8.3.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://www.bewolfclothing.com/elevatezoom/jquery.elevatezoom.js'></script> Can you fix this links at first?